# Laravel > localization > How can i specify App::setlocale() for specific routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, localization

I have an application with many modules (module mean list of controllers), I want to make App::setlocale() works with the current module that user choose to change language on, and other modules still as the last time user choose

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do a bit more of an effort to search...

http://nielson.io/2014/05/easy-route-localization-in-laravel-using-filters/

This tells you the answer. Good luck!